# How to make reading client request module very efficient (HTTP)?

Tags: java, algorithm, http, webserver, buffer

I am building my *HTTP WEB SERVER* . In this project I made one module that reads clients request, but that is very inefficient. So please suggest some suggestion, how can I make this module very efficient. I am sharing my code that performs reading request task. See below,

Waiting for your suggestions. THanks in advance.

**Part of my code**

```
final static int BUF_SIZE = 2048;
byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
private Socket s;
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
int nread = 0, r = 0;

    outerloop:
    while (nread < BUF_SIZE) {
        r = is.read(buf, nread, BUF_SIZE - nread);
        if (r == -1) {
            /* EOF */
            return;
        }
        int i = nread;
        nread += r;
        for (; i < nread; i++) {
            if (buf[i] == (byte) '\n' || buf[i] == (byte) '\r') {
                /* read one line */
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT NO. 1**

Below is the request from client, that is stored in `is`

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

This is end by special character \r or \n.

How can I put this in buffer using any optimized method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up everything, i would consider switching from `java.io` to `java.nio`.

Further Information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O
 or just google it ;)

Comment: I am reading `java.nio` functionalities, as you advised. If I find any doubt I will be ask with you. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading lines, use BufferedReader.readLine(). At present you're processing every character twice. But I see no reason to think there is any major inefficiency here, considering the entire process will be network-bound.

Comment: See Edit no. 1. I tried using `BufferedReader`, but I didn't get the idea. Please help me.

Comment: Define "didn't get the idea".

Comment: This request is placed in InputStream. I didn't get the method to move this request into Buffer. I tried `java.nio`, but I didn't suitable method. Can you please tell me what method should me used to fill buffer from InputStream, and further I have to process my buffer first few characters as it contains Request type, i.e., GET, PUT, HEAD etc.